# KVM-QEMU virtualization platform issue with creating guests of red-hat based distributions

Tags: linux, kvm, qemu

I do use virtualization a lot , and of course my favorite tool is kvkm-qemu. However I am extremely frustrated with it lately, all my attempts to create a redhat based virtual machine with  centos,opensuse and etc has failed so far and I cannot pinpoint the issue in any way.

I try to create the virtual machine using the virt-manager on my own host and after successful installation I transfer the host to the container machine. The funny part is that I created a centos guest 2 weeks ago successfully and painfully . The guest will stuck for no reason at different stages of the boot, I force reboot and then boots and stucks again is somewhere else , sometimes it boots up completely but cant run the setup , I changed all of my iso files I re-downloaded them and verified them , I tried different settings for hardware and also tried nomodeset with the kernel, it boots it installs but then it wont boot again.

Out of my frustration I used the virtualbox and vmware workstation to create the guests flawlessly then converted the guests for the container machine successfully but again they wont boot with this method.

I assign:

```
1X cpu 
512 MB of ram
30GB HDD
```

to each guest. Anyway so here is the annoying part, when creating a debian based guest such as ubuntu :-/ it just like 1,2,3 piece of cake no issues and no  matter how I do it and on whichever virtualbbox,kvm or vmware then convert it to raw or .qcow2 it works. I bet even if I transfer it to the mars it will still work. Its so annoying.

I USE:

```
[root@athena odin]# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="29 (Workstation Edition)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=29
VERSION_CODENAME=""
PLATFORM_ID="platform:f29"
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 29 (Workstation Edition)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
LOGO=fedora-logo-icon
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:29"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f29/system-administrators-guide/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Communicating_and_getting_help"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=29
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=29
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy"
VARIANT="Workstation Edition"
VARIANT_ID=workstation


[root@athena odin]# lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:            9
CPU MHz:             1000.019
CPU max MHz:         3500.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            4992.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp flush_l1d


              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          11887        5467         771         608        5648        5489
Swap:          6011        1006        5005
```

as my HOST machine. with the kernel version of 5.0.5-200.fc29.x86_64. the basic settings that i use for each guest in kvm is as follows:

[image]

btw. the reason I create the guests on a different machine is that the container machine is headless and I have better flexibility doing what I do here. I can test the guests before doing the actual thing on the container for security reasons , but still if I do it on the container ( I tried ) directly it won't work at all. The container is AMD based CPU and my workstation is INTEL.

Comment: Why do you call the other machine "container machine"? Why don't you just create the VM directly on that machine? You already have virt-manager, just set up a new connection.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the obvious but a container machine as it indicates contains a cluster of virtual machines. it however has been modified for security reasons based on various standards. we do have linux based containers which are kvm based or you can just create your own container machine anyhow you desire.

Comment: This is very confusing. You keep saying "container" but that word doesn't make sense in the context you have used it. You seem to be talking about virtual machines, but containers are something else entirely, and I don't understand why you mention containers at all here? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Dont be confused it is very simple , virtual machines will be created and tested before transferring them to the container server and bringing them to production. You dont directly create virtual machines on the container system that would be against our security policy . Each guest must be tested and passes all the security checks before it being allowed on the container system.

Comment: There are thousands of terms used in computing some might have similar names but entirely different definitions. Kubernetes and cloud also have container in their definitions. On this particular subject we refer to linux containers which are servers capable of virtualization in large scale, securing them is another practice.  For example VMware EXSI SERVER is a container OS. You install it on a bare metal or just a very powerful server and it will host tens of guest machines and it is called container.

Comment: And in security we have containerizing strategy which is absolutely another thing irrelevant to this. So dont let the term confuse you. Let's stay on the issue as stated.

Comment: so to translate ypur meaning: you are building a VM on one host and then you move it to another host. No containers (docker, CRI) involved.

Comment: how do you do the transfer between hosts?

Comment: My words are not ambiguous  I'm simply talking about a linux virtualization container rest assured if u was going to discuss docker, CRI I would've said so , moving it is not the issue , the issue is that Any redhat based distribution simply will not boot up for installation as I stated. We are talking about redhat , centos,  opensuse , SME .... all of the derivatives of red hat. I cant imagine how you never heard of a linux container or container OS etc... even so the container and transfering the VM is not the case its booting up the installer that is the main issue here.

Comment: For someone asking for help, you need to take the self assuredness and general attitude down a notch, if you want people to want to help you. 

Containers are a very specific technology, not the same as Virtual Machines, and trust me, I've been a part of the KVM team from when they were a small startup that invented KVM. You want to invent your own terminology - you're welcome to it, but don't be surprised when people don't get your imaginary world. 

Now, back to the issue - how exactly are you migrating those VMs over to the second host?

Comment: Look guys , imagine I want to install centos as a guest . I have VMware workstation , virtual box and kvm. Alright? Since the final destination is kvm based so I need the virtual disk images to be something that kvm supports like qcow2 or img or vmdk . Right? If I use the virtual box or VMware workstation to create they work fine but the final product will not boot up in kvm at all. If I use kvm elsewhere to create it then the installer wont boot up at all , but for debian I have no issue .

Comment: Can you post the domxml and the qemu cmdline before and after migration, as well as the server specs at both source and destination?

Comment: The specs are indicated in the main question but I will provide the other detail in a couple of hours. I have found a quick guide regarding the issue I will be trying that as well if that works I'll post the answer here. Pretty sure this is something extremely simple that is causing this but just have to figure it out .

Comment: You posted the source machine, as fedora 29, with a simple i5 CPU. Nothing about the destination host besides "it is big". Please update on that as well. There might be differences if the host OS there isn't the same as yours and if it's using different CPUs. libvirt and qemi-kvm versions also matter.

Comment: alright , the only issue here is with the source machine. no redhat derivative can load on this machine , it cannot launch the installer , the installation gets stuck in various stages for no reason whatsoever . the destination machine is not in the equation here at all . we are talking about the source machine if you will. all debian based distributions can launch their setup successfully and all red hat based distros will fail to boot the setup . regardless of the fact as suggested i assigned 10gb of ram and 2x cpu for the setup to load.

Comment: [root@athena odin]# qemu-kvm  -version
QEMU emulator version 3.0.0 (qemu-3.0.0-4.fc29)
Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
this is the SOURCE machine which i am creating the virtual machines before transferring them to production, i did not have this issue before , i had this issue once and rebooting the centos setup 5 times did the trick but now it is impossible launch ANY red hat based distro .

Comment: and here is the Destination if you thats what you want to call it (or else known as the container) , its a more stable version tho.
QEMU emulator version 2.11.2(openSUSE Leap 15.0)
Copyright (c) 2003-2017 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

Comment: and the containers cpu :

Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          21
Model:               16
Model name:          AMD A4-5300B APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Stepping:            1
CPU MHz:             3393.950
BogoMIPS:            6787.90
Virtualization:      AMD-V

Comment: take note , the container(destination machine) has no role in this equation at all. the issue persists on the workstation which is used to create the vm guests

Answer (score 0):

- CentOS 7.0 is quite obsolete, does it fail also with recent 7.6?
- 512MB of RAM is far low under RHEL/CentOS7 recommendations - 2GB. It is probably too little!

Comment: i forgot to mention that i have downloaded the latest ISO from the centos , and also assigned 2gb ram for the installation purposes, i do have a centos 7.6 created with the minimal specifications i stated such as 512 MB of ram and it works perfectly , but that was two weeks ago as i said and for that one i literally had to reset the machine 25 Times before it could bring up the installation . i am baffled with this issue i cant seem to pinpoint what the problem is .

Comment: Also I cant pinpoint why after like a hundred times restarting the installation it stucks in various stages , it progresses then stucks somewhere else then again after rebooting it passes that stage then get stuck somewhere else , I have tried increasing the number of CPU and the RAM to 8GB and 4 CPU. to pass the minimal requirements but still nothing. Now if I'm to install any debian derivative it goes without any issue even with 256mb of ram. This bothers me why debian is ok with it but not Any of the redhat derivatives.